# PHP MVC correct redirecting, is die needed?

Tags: php, redirect, model-view-controller, exit

What is the correct way to redirect to another controller in a PHP MVC structure?

Lets say i have my controller class:

```
abstract class controller {

    public function __construct() {
        // code here
    }

    abstract protected function index();

    protected function redirect($location = 'index') {
        header('location:' . URL . $location);
        die(); // <-not shure if this die is right here
    }

}
```

And in another class i need to verify a condition and redirect to another place if false

```
class loginController extends controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // More code here
    }

    public function index() {
        if ($this->session->verifyUserStatus()) {
            $this->redirect('admin');
        }
        $this->view->render('login');
    }
}
```

Should i need to call die() function at the end of the redirector? or just ending the script normally will be fine?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can simply end it normally, die() isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the ideal case, you would not explicitly kill it as the framework might have other things it wants to do that aren't registered for the shutdown signal. Such a framework would also not requre one to use the `header()` function inside a controller as that is untestable. Instead, a controller could do something like `return Redirect::to($path);` and let the framework set the appropriate headers.

If dealing with poor quality, procedural code, killing it explicitly is ok.

Comment: but my guess is that not killing it will cause the script to continue and render the login view, i know it will happen very fast and the user wont nottice it, but what if instead of that i have a time intensive function?

Comment: [Browsers are configured to ignore the body](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7060595/5113242) if the `Location` header is present.